# Pygame sprite group using random.rand

Tags: python, animation, random, pygame

I am working with a sprite group which contains 60 sprite objects.
each object represents a asteroid image and all images displayed after each other in the right order creates an animation of a rotating asteroid, in other words i am iterating through the sprite group as seen in code below.

Evcerything works fine until the objects passes the screen height and resets at the top again and the objects then starts appearing at random locations in the x direction. The screen now seem to blit each sprite at random locations and the asteroid now just flickers back and forth horizontally.

Is there a way to get the same new random x location for all the sprites after asteroid obj passes the screen instead of giving each sprite in the group a new x value?

Any suggestions?

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import random
import time
import math

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (200, 40, 60)
green = (50, 180, 50)
blue = (50, 30, 200)
skyblue = (135, 206, 250)
silver = (192, 192, 192)
darkgray = (47, 79, 79)
vegasgold = (197, 179, 88)
nightblue = (25, 25, 112)
steelblue = (70, 130, 180)
deepblue = (0, 26, 51)

screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
half_width = screen_width/2
half_height = screen_height/2

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
Title = pygame.display.set_caption('Space Mash')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width=30, height=30, color=white):
        super(Spaceship, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0

    def center_set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x - self.rect.center[0]
        self.rect.y = y - self.rect.width

    def rotate_ship(self, dg):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, dg)

    def set_image(self, filename):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def draw_ship(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y])


player_spaceship = Spaceship()
player_spaceship.set_image("main_ship.png")
player_spaceship.center_set_position(half_width, screen_height)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player_spaceship)


class Asteroids(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, nr):
        super(Asteroids, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('Asteroid_{0}.png'.format(nr))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 5

        if self.rect.y > screen_height + 50:
            self.rect.y = -50
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, (screen_width - (self.rect.width))


asteroids_list = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates() 

for i in range(1, 61):
    asteroid = Asteroids(nr=i)

    asteroids_list.add(asteroid)
    all_sprites_list.add(asteroid)



class Stars(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Stars, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([1, 1])
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

stars_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


def making_star_objects():

    for i in range(100):
        x_loc = random.randint(0, screen_width - 1)
        y_loc = random.randint(0, screen_height - 1)
        star = Stars()
        star.rect.x = x_loc
        star.rect.y = y_loc

        stars_group.add(star)


def gameloop():
    ending = False
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0
    making_star_objects()
    frame = 0

    while not ending:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -8
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 8
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = 0


        player_spaceship.rect.x += x_change
        player_spaceship.rect.y += y_change
        if frame > 59:
            frame = 0

        asteroids_list.update()


        asteroids_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_spaceship, asteroids_list, False)

        screen.fill(deepblue)
        stars_group.draw(screen)
        screen.blit(asteroids_list.get_sprite(frame).image, (asteroids_list.get_sprite(frame).rect.x,
                                                        asteroids_list.get_sprite(frame).rect.y))



        frame += 1

        player_spaceship.draw_ship()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a **Class variable** property and store the first coordinate X assigned, then reuse the value when you need it. It will be accessible from all the objects, since is a class global variable.

If you assign the value to the variable by this way, it will be the same (if you don't change it) during all the execution of the program, because it's value is assigned when the class is created.

`rectXCopy = random.randrange(0, (screen_width - (self.rect.width))`

Finaly, your class will become like this:

```
class Asteroids(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    rectXCopy = random.randrange(0, (screen_width - (self.rect.width))
    def __init__(self, nr):
        super(Asteroids, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('Asteroid_{0}.png'.format(nr))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.rectYCopy = 0
        self.copied = False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 5

        if self.rect.y > screen_height + 50:
            self.rect.y = -50
            self.rect.x = self.rectXcopy
```

Comment: the update method sets all sprites in the group to a new individual rect.x value but i want the rect.x to be the same for all objects since theyre all part of the same animation.

Comment: so you want the first `rect.x` value assigned to be the same for all sprites?

Comment: if you have python and pygame installed you can just copy my code and get the program running:)

Comment: In that case, I'll update the code soon, wait a sec.

Comment: Code updated, check it out  and tell me ;) PS: I didn't have pygame, so I can't check :( @DanielBäck

Comment: Tyvm this helped alot!:)

Comment: Now the sprites will always appear at the same position after they leave the screen. You'd need a function to iterate over the `asteroids_list` and change the positions of all sprites together if you want to set them to a new random pos. This will probably get troublesome if you want to have more than one asteroid on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have all the animation frames as separate sprite objects in your `asteroids_list` sprite group. They all have their own rects and if you update one of them, the others aren't affected. So when the sprites leave the screen you set them all to different random positions.

I recommend to create **only one** asteroid object, put the images into a list or dict (whatever you prefer) and then just change the image of this single asteroid sprite in its update method to create the animation.

```
# Put the images / pygame.Surfaces into a global constant list.
ASTEROID_FRAMES = [surface1, surface2]  # etc. (use a list comprehension)

class Asteroids(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, nr):
        super(Asteroids, self).__init__()
        self.image = ASTEROID_FRAMES[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))
        self.frame = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 5

        if self.rect.y > screen_height + 50:
            self.rect.y = -50
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, (screen_width - (self.rect.width)))

        # Update the image (this is frame rate bound, but you can also
        # add a timer to change the frame after some time has passed).
        self.frame += 1
        # Keep the index in the correct range.
        self.frame %= len(ASTEROID_FRAMES)
        self.image = ASTEROID_FRAMES[self.frame]
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful or should I explain anything more detailed?